# Split UNIX String with DOT delimiter and store in variable

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, split

I have a file `abc.123.234.345` and I want to store value of `123.234.345` into variable1 using UNIX oneliner.
Then I have to rename a file named `def` as `def.123.234.345`
I tried `sed`, `awk` but not able to generate split string.

I have to search as `abc.*.*.*` as string will be different every time.

Any suggestions?

Some sample that I use but not working

```
FILE=abc.*.*.* | mv /loc/def /loc/def.${FILE#*.}
```

Comment: I just want to update the numbers from **def** to **def**.123.234.345 and not **abc**.123.234.345

Comment: The source file in your move command is `/loc/def`.  You cannot it move it more than once.  What file do you want to have for the source the second time that you find a `abc.*.*.*` file?

Comment: I want to get the value of abc... and update def first

Comment: everytime there will be new file which I have to rename and move

Comment: Another clarification: You write _"I have a string `abc.123.234.345`"_ but the sample code that you provide makes it look like `abc.123.234.345` is a file name.  Which is it?

Comment: Ok so that is a file name which I am getting as string

Comment: I have edited from string to file

Comment: Do you already have the string or do you need to get it from the file name?  Will there be just one such file?  Will it always be found in the current directory?

Comment: I have to get the string name ie file name. yes 1 file at a time but every run will update the file name. yes always in current directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer for revised question

For the question as revised in the most recent comment for which there is only one file matching the glob `abc.*.*.*` and that file is in the current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'abc.*.*.*' -exec bash -c 'mv /loc/def "/loc/def.${1#./*.}"' none {} \;
```

Or, in two steps:

```
file=$(echo abc.*.*.*)
mv /loc/def "/loc/def.${file#./*.}"
```

Note that it is best practice to use names for shell variables that are lower or mixed case.  The system uses upper case names for its variables and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.

#### Answer for original question

This does what you ask:

```
find . -name 'abc.*.*.*' -exec bash -c 'mv /loc/def "/loc/def.${1#./*.}"' none {} \;
```

The above execute `mv` commands such as:

```
mv /loc/def /loc/def.123.234.345
```

Note that, after the first `mv` command, `/loc/def` will no longer exist and the second `mv` command will therefore fail.